# cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

Tags: c

Нужно сделать практическую на языке С. Язык вообще не понимаю и как-то плохо он мною усваивается. Потому прошу помочь и, по возможности, объяснить.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Находим простое число с порядковым номером N, где N — это
значение, на которое указывает параметр ARG. */
void* compute_prime(void* arg)
{
    int candidate = 2;
    int n = *((int*)arg);
    while (1) 
    {
        int factor;
        int is_prime = 1;
        /* Проверка простого числа путем последовательного деления. */
        for (factor = 2; factor < candidate; ++factor)
            if (candidate % factor == 0)
            {
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        /* Это то простое число, которое нам нужно? */
        if (is_prime)
        {
            if (--n == 0)
                /* Возвращаем найденное число в программу. */
                return (void*)candidate;
        }
        ++candidate;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    int which_prime = 5000;
    int prime;
    /* Запускаем поток, вычисляющий 5000-е простое число. */
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, &which_prime);
    /* Выполняем другие действия. */
    /* Дожидаемся завершения потока и принимаем возвращаемое им
    значение. */
    pthread_join(thread, (void*)&prime);
    /* Отображаем вычисленный результат. */
    printf("The %dth prime number is %d.n", which_prime, prime);
    return 0;
}
```

Выбивает ошибку в 21 строке:

> cast to pointer from integer of different size
>   [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]  return (void*)candidate;

Подскажите как решить проблему и объясните в чем именно дело?

Comment: Разрешить ситуацию можно заменив `int candidate = 2;` на `long candidate = 2;`. Но проблемы кода гораздо шире.

Comment: Спасибо, я в будущем всё равно на С не собираюсь кодить. Мне больше приглянулся PHP и C#

Comment: Фу какая ужасная табуляция((( Поэтому C так плохо вами усваивается. Код писать красиво нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за некропостинг

Answer (score 1):

тут 2 ошибки

- return предполагает указатель на candidate, а в коде указано просто candidate. Самый очевидный ответ (хотя и неверный) - вернуть указатель - то есть использовать '&candidate' (знак & и значит вернуть указатель на эту переменную)
- но есть еще один нюанс, очень "хитрый" - это уже из области использования стека. Даже если вернуть указатель на эту переменную, то появиться другая ошибка - 'function returns address of local variable'. Дело в том что когда объявляешь переменную - она создается в стеке. И когда выходишь из функции, стек исчезает, и переменная вместе с ним. И попытка обратиться извне к этой переменной (когда мы печатаем значение в main) может вывести что-угодно. Поэтому следует сделать эту переменную не локальной, а разместить ее в куче (heap). Для этого испоьзуется malloc - эта функция "бронирует" память вне стека. И после использования - free() - эта функция снимает "бронь". И соответственно работать с этой переменной нужно через указатель

Вот как будет выглядеть программа

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void* compute_prime(void* arg)
{
   int *p_candidate = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *p_candidate = 2;
   int n = *((int*)arg);
   while (1)
   {
      int factor;
      int is_prime = 1;
      for (factor = 2; factor < (*p_candidate); ++factor)
      if (*p_candidate % factor == 0)
      {
         is_prime = 0;
         break;
      }
      if (is_prime)
      {
         if (--n == 0)
         return (void*)p_candidate;
      }
      ++(*p_candidate);
   }
   return &n;
   return NULL;
}
int main()
{
   pthread_t thread;
   int which_prime = 5000;
   int *prime = NULL;
   pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, &which_prime);
   pthread_join(thread, (void*)&prime);
   if (prime != NULL)
   {
      printf("The %dth prime number is %d\n", which_prime, *prime);
      free (prime);
   }
   else
   {
      printf ("error");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

(увы пришлось убрать коменты, ибо у меня на линухе проблемы с русским языком)